# Instantiate a Singleton in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to instantiate an object with a singleton in c#.

```
    private static Mario __instance;
    public static Mario Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (__instance == null)
            {
                __instance = new Mario(); //TODO correct this vector
            }
            return __instance;
        }
    }

    public Mario() 
    {
        position = Vector2.Zero;
        theatre = XNATheatre.Theatre;
        ActionState = new IdleState();
        PreviousState = ActionState;
        ActionState.Enter(null);
        isFacingRight = true;
    }
```

I also have an idlestate class that is being instantiated in mario's constructor:

```
    public IdleState()
    {
        mario = Mario.Instance;
        Console.WriteLine(mario);
    }
```

What seems to be happening is the _instance variable in my singleton always remains null, therefore it keeps returning new instances of mario, exactly the opposite of what I want it to do. I'm not exactly sure how to get around this.

Comment: "What seems to be happening is the _instance variable in my singleton always remains null, therefore it keeps returning new instances of mario," if that were true then the `Instance` property would return null, not a new instance of `Mario`. I think we need to go back a step and figure out why you think a new instance of `Mario` is being created every time. Your `Instance` property does create a singleton (albeit not thread safe).

Comment: Given the code you posted, you should eventually get a `StackOverflowException`, and never see the `Mario.Instance` property return. But your problem description mentions none of this, and if you had gotten an exception, you'd be able to look at the stack trace and see the recursive calling and see for yourself what was wrong. So, what problem are you actually seeing? Please provide a good [mcve] and a more specific, clear problem description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a circular dependency...
When instantiating a Mario you instantiate an IdleState which calls Mario.Instance instantiating a new Mario and repeat.